# Barcode128 barcode is thicker and not scannable in iText pdf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, itext, barcode

I am generating code128 type barcodes, then converting it to image and then printing it on itext pdf pdfcell. The barcodes are fitting inside the cell, but the issue is the bars are thicker than it should be.
And that is why probably they are not scannable.
Can you please help on how to scael it prperly.

> Below is the code-

```
Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();

              code128.setCode(bc.trim());

              code128.setCodeType(Barcode128.CODE128_UCC);

              code128.setBarHeight(15f);

              System.out.println("GETX" + code128.getX());

              code128.setX(.3f);

              System.out.println("After setX" + code128.getX());



              java.awt.Image rawImage = code128.createAwtImage(Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE);

              Image img = Image.getInstance(rawImage, null);

              img.setBorder(Image.ORIGINAL_NONE);
            return img;
```

> and in the itext pdf, i'm using -

```
    PdfPCell cell_header_barcode = new PdfPCell(BarCode.createBarcode(""+123456 ));
cell_header_barcode.setRowspan(4);

cell_header_barcode.setPaddingTop(6);
cell_header_barcode.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
cell_header_barcode.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
cell_header_barcode.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
cell_header_barcode.setRowspan(4);
table_header.addCell(cell_header_barcode);
doc.add(table_header);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "thicker than it should be" mean? Can you post an _image_ of the barcode relative to some text so that we can see it?

Comment: Hello @ChrisHaas , i have added two images. Please look into it

Comment: Thanks. Can you also post your table code? Something in there appears to be stretching the image.

Comment: hello @ChrisHaas, also added the code snippet. Please check once if that help you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: also please let me know if the provided info is not enough for you.

Comment: You should try to use SVG, the result is much better

Comment: Hello All, i have resolved the issue by changing the barcode generation method. Now im using code128.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null) method for generating the barcode and set code128.setFont(null) so that the default text dosen't appear under the barcode.  Thank you very much for looking into my issue.